Do you have any interesting CSS ideas how to create beautiful file structure
I say about tree file structure like 
But i want to make some more modern variant. Do you have some ideas or links. Maybe in your cheat sheet there are some modern and interesting ideas to make tree file structure. I try to make myself but all, i make, i don't like, so i want to take some idea as base and make it better.

AWS S3 has pretty nice structure display.
